# How to close the chrome window that is opened by applying the code webbrowser.open?

Tags: python, import

I imported webbrowser in the very beginning of this file. The whole code was like this in the below.

```
import time 
import webbrowser

break_times = 3
break_count = 0


print ("Program started at: " + time.ctime())
while break_count < break_times :
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m69d-KNi2Q0")
    break_count = break_count + 1
```

But I am stuck here. The code opens my chrome browser but I couldn't close it using code. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: *I* would rather use `selenium` than `webbrowser` for browse automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `selenium`.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

break_times = 3
break_count = 0

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

print("Program started at: " + time.ctime())
while break_count < break_times:
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m69d-KNi2Q0")
    break_count = break_count + 1

browser.close()
```